# How to Add Reference to a netstandard 2.0 Nuget from VS2013 .Net Framework 4.8 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, csproj, .net-standard-2.0

I have a vs 2013 project which targets .net framework 4.8. I need to add a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting nuget package but when I do I get the following error on package manager console.

```
Error message:

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting -Version 2.2.0

Installing 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0'.

You are downloading Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/2.0.0/LICENSE.txt. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.

Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0'.

Adding 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0' to QuartzExample.

Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0'.

Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0'.

Install failed. Rolling back...

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into

a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content

files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

At line:1 char:1

+ Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting -Version 2.2.0

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

My Project File looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{07E02FE5-9E9B-434D-B6A2-D037DE7CE6CA}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>QuartzExample</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>QuartzExample</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Quartz, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Quartz.3.0.7\lib\net452\Quartz.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Quartz.Jobs, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Quartz.Jobs.3.0.7\lib\net452\Quartz.Jobs.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Quartz.Plugins, Version=3.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Quartz.Plugins.3.0.7\lib\net452\Quartz.Plugins.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Remoting" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyJob.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="quartz_jobs.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

My App.Config is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>

  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>

  <quartz>    
    <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz.Plugins" />
    <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/quartz_jobs.xml" />
  </quartz>
</configuration>
```

Without updating Visual Studio 2013, can I add references to a .netstandard2 nuget such as Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. VS2013 has an ancient version of NuGet which doesn't know anything about .NET Standard and therefore can't know that .NET Standard 2.0 is compatible with the .NET Framework 4.8.

If you really can't upgrade to a newer Visual Studio, maybe you can look into .NET Core. Visual Studio Code is a tiny installation and provides good .NET development experience, otherwise any text editor will do, you just lose intellisense if you can't use something that supports Omnisharp.